# OpenCV's distance transform giving weird results near border

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I noticed that [distanceTransform](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=distancetransform#cv2.distanceTransform) from opencv yields weird results, e.g the following code:

```
arr = numpy.zeros((6, 6), numpy.uint8)
(distance, labels) = cv2.distanceTransform(arr, cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L1, cv2.cv.CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
print 'array\n', arr
print '\ndistance\n', distance
```

prints:

```
array
[[0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]

distance
[[ 2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 2.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.]]
```

Why are there any positive values near the borders? I have even weirder results when I execute this:

```
arr = numpy.zeros((6, 6), numpy.uint8)
arr[1:-1,1:-1] = 255

(distance, labels) = cv2.distanceTransform(arr, cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L1, cv2.cv.CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE)
distance = distance.astype(numpy.uint8)
print 'array\n', arr
print '\ndistance\n', distance
```

gives:

```
array
[[  0   0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255 255 255 255   0]
 [  0 255 255 255 255   0]
 [  0 255 255 255 255   0]
 [  0 255 255 255 255   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0   0]]

distance
[[ 8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.]
 [ 8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.]
 [ 8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.]
 [ 8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.]
 [ 8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.]
 [ 8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.  8192.]]
```

Comment: update:

I've tested similar code using c++ API and I noticed that I have the same wrong results only when I execute the version of distancetransform that returns labels as well
 `(void distanceTransform(InputArray? src, OutputArray? dst, OutputArray? labels, int distanceType, int maskSize)`

 The other version w/o labels works fine (`void distanceTransform(InputArray? src, OutputArray? dst, OutputArray? labels, int distanceType, int maskSize`).

It looks like python wrapper always executes the latter buggy one. I reported a bug here:

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1531